# What does "!w /mnt" mean in shell?

Tags: bash

I opened a directory over terminal and there is !w before directory.

So what does !w before directory mean and how is it called in the manpages?

[image]

Comment: What is the output from `echo "$PS1"`  ??

Answer (score 3):

The `!w` part re-executes that last command which started with `w`.

The  `/mnt` means to add that onto command to be executed.

Therefor, if the last command to start with `w` was `wibble /home`, then the new command to run will be `wibble /home /mnt`.

However as per @roaima stated below, perhaps someone misdirected output. I would imagine it can be safely deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is something the OP typed; more something they saw (such as a prompt)

Comment: I added a screenshot, maybe its more helpful as only a typed description

Comment: It's a redirection error. Check the size and its contents. There could be nothing in it. I would suggest that you can delete it without issue by `rm \!w*`, although that `/mnt` part seems strange as it should not be creatable.

Comment: Looks like a weird prompt string to me.